# How to read a PGN file for parsing in objective - c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parsing

I've got a PGN file called a00.PGN in my project, which I'd like to parse to 'preload' into Core Data.  Right now I'm just trying to output the file as a string with `NSLog` using

```
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSString *datapath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a00" ofType:@"PGN"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:datapath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&err];
    NSLog(@"%@", err);
```

And I'm getting an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The file name is invalid."

When I NSLog the string content it is NULL.

I have tried changing the extension to .txt but the same error is received, and have also used NSUTF8StringEncoding.  What is the best way to read in this file for parsing in objective-c?

Edit 1:

To include the file in my project I dragged it from finder.  I then went to my projects target and added it to the `Copy Files` section with Products Directory as the destination.  The Subpath is empty.

Edit 2:

I've uploaded the current state of this simple project to a repo here: https://github.com/justinjdickow/PGN-Parse-into-Core-Data/

Comment: It's much faster to store only the path to the image you want to store in Core Data. Otherwise your database will grow extremely fast! You can create a "container" for your images just like iPhoto or Aperture do.

Comment: Is it an image or just a non-stanadard file extension?

Comment: It's just a non-standard file extension.  It's a text file that I can read with any text editor.  It's not an image.

Comment: Oh my fault ... I just read `PNG` ... sorry!

Comment: Have you double-checked that the file is included in the target, in addition to having been added to the project?

Comment: Yes, it is included in the copy files in the products directory destination.  I do not know if I should change the Subpath or how to know what the Subpath should be.

Comment: If you're on the simulator you can print out the contents of `datapath` and check if its actually showing the correct path, since it will be to a file on your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Technical Q&A QA1436: What is the "main bundle" of a command-line foundation tool?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1436/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004115) — actually, that document is (partially) wrong.

In a command-line tool executable, the main bundle's path would be the directory that contains the executable itself. For example, in a sample command-line tool project I made here, the following was logged to console:

```
mainBundle == NSBundle <~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mainBundle-bqmiidcdlnwumjgcnblqgtelpecl/Build/Products/Debug> (loaded),
bundlePath == ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mainBundle-bqmiidcdlnwumjgcnblqgtelpecl/Build/Products/Debug
```

In other words, the main bundle will be your built-products directory. For `NSBundle`'s `pathForResource:ofType:` to be able to find the "A00.PGN" file at runtime, that file will need to be in your built-products directory along with your executable. For example, in my case, I would need the file to be located at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mainBundle-bqmiidcdlnwumjgcnblqgtelpecl/Build/Products/Debug/A00.PGN`

The easiest way to achieve that is to add a `Copy Files` build phase to your command line tool target. Specify the Destination as the Products Directory and include the A00.PGN file in the list of files to be copied.

Also, as others have already mentioned, `NSBundle`'s search method is case-sensitive even if the underlying HFS+ file system on OS X is merely case-preserving. So, make sure you specify the correct filename and filename extension in your code.

Comment: This information was included in the tutorial that I was following so I had already done it.  The a00.PGN file is included there with a destination of "Products Directory" and Subpath "usr/share/man/man1", which was entered automatically. I've also made sure that the case of my strings matches that of the file name.  How can I confirm the Subpath of the Products Directory?  What else could be causing this error?

Comment: You should remove the subpath entry. That's probably there from the default "Copy Files" build phase which is intended to copy the "man-page" (the documentation help file) for your tool to the appropriate location. Since you're reusing that same phase for your purposes, you should remove the subpath entry, otherwise it will be copying it to `.../Build/Products/Debug/usr/share/man/man1/a00.PGN` instead of `.../Build/Products/Debug/a00.PGN`. Alternatively, you could create 2 separate Copy Files phases, and copy the respective files to the appropriate location in each.

Comment: I removed the path and am still getting the same error.  I also tried making the Subpath the same as the path contained in my datapath string.

Comment: @JuJoDi: Sorry, you should also uncheck the "Copy only when installing" checkbox. You can always right-click the icon for the Product in the left hand column and choose "Show in Finder". When I did that, I could see that there was no a00.PGN file copied (in my sample project). Once I unchecked "Copy only when installing" it finally worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `pathForResource:ofType:` has different case-sensitivity depending whether it is iPhone simulator or iPad simulator or the device.

Make sure you are using upper/lower case consistently.

Comment: This is an Objective-C Command Line Tool built in xcode, although I have tried matching the case of the actual file as well to no avail.